# How to Estimate the mean and covariances for all classes from training set?

Tags: matlab

A training set of 2000 samples ( value :2000 * 2 ) named training_set. how can i estimate the mean and covariances for all classes from training set. already tried mean and cov function.but every time get " Undefined function or variable " error.
Just a beginner. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. You have row vectors and the mean would be a row vector as well.

Matlab:  training_mean = mean(training_set,1);

the cov function in matlab should work fine and your result should be a 2 by 2 matrix. Matlab has good documentation for this kind of things.

Comment: tried this way...but still undefined function or variable

training_mean = mean(training_data,1);

Comment: is your data composed of row vectors? or make sure it is. try this on matlab command prompt. create a matrx A = ones(3,2). compute the mean with mean(A,1)--> which is row mean  or mean(A,2)--> which is a mean of columns